# Does Firefox support .ttc fonts?

Tags: css, web-fonts, html

I have the following css:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'font name';
src: url('../font/fontname.ttc');
}
```

In Chrome it is working but in the firefox the font style doesn't apply, font get too bold not cleared. Am i doing something wrong? or I have to convert this file into .ttf.

Answer (score 4):

Firefox has not been advertized to support TTC. In general, it is best to use services like the [FontSquirrel generator](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator) to produce different font formats for different browsers. If you need help with the quality of font rendering, you need to specify the actual font used, the full CSS code for using it, and the platform(s) on which you observed problems (font rendering varies by platform, partly by browser and settings too).